# Dynamically changing image in a picturebox

Tags: c#, dynamic, picturebox

I'd like to run a piece of code which keeps changing the picture of a picturebox (like a rotating propeller) until the form is closed.

I managed to change the picture of the PictureBox with an EventHandler, but I don't know how to go along.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }

    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
    {
        Location = new Point(0, 0),
        SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
        Size = new Size(300,300),
        ImageLocation = @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png"
    };

    private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pb.ImageLocation == @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png")
        {
            pb.ImageLocation =@"E:\folder\gas_jo_1.png";
        }
        else if (pb.ImageLocation == @"E:\folder\gas_jo_1.png")
        {
            pb.ImageLocation = @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you still want to do?

Comment: change the picture in an infinite cycle. When I start the program, I'd like the picture to be automatically changed from gas_jo.png to gas_jo_1.png and so on.

Comment: You want to change Image of pictureBox in an interval of some seconds?

Comment: Exactly, Sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Controls.Add(pb);

    timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000;
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) => {
        if (pb.ImageLocation == @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png")
        {
            pb.ImageLocation =@"E:\folder\gas_jo_1.png";
        }
        else if (pb.ImageLocation == @"E:\Real-time_Imi\gas_jo_1.png")
        {
            pb.ImageLocation = @"E:\Real-time_Imi\gas_jo.png";
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}

PictureBox pb = new PictureBox
{
    Location = new Point(0, 0),
    SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom,
    Size = new Size(300,300),
    ImageLocation = @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] pictureBoxArray = new string[] { @"E:\folder\gas_jo.png", @"E:\folder\gas_jo_1.png", @"E:\folder\gas_jo_2.png" };

    int pctIndex = 0;  

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {


                 pb.ImageLocation = pictureBoxArray[pctIndex]; 
                    pctIndex ++;  
                    if(pctIndex==pictureBoxArray.Length)
                        pctIndex =0 ;  
            }
```