# Determine if two images are identical

Tags: c#, image

Is there any way to determine if two images are identical?
I want to change an image every time my timer ticks (animation).
But, I need to see which image is displaying, so is there any way to compare 2 images
to do what I want?

```
if (myImage.Flags == (Image.FromFile(@"Images/Enemy.png").Flags))
{
     myImage = Image.FromFile(@"Images/Enemy2.png");
}
else 
{
     myImage = Image.FromFile(@"Images/Enemy.png");
}
```

Comment: You don't compare images. You keep the information in separate variable.

Comment: I guess you could calculate hash values of both files and then compare the hashes.

Comment: Are all of the images different file names?  If so this should be *really* easy

Comment: Compare by what? Image itself, size, name, or..?

Comment: Looks like you're just alternating between two images. You could do something like `myImage = (_count++ % 2 == 1)? "Enemy.png" : "Enemy2.png"`

Comment: @BobKaufman, it will **only** works until you reach `MaxValue` ? =D

Comment: @Sinatr No.  It will work forever, so long as you aren't running it in a checked context (which is the default state).  You can explicitly wrap it in an `unchecked` block if that's a concern.

Comment: @Sinatr - I agree with you that depending on the context, as Servy has pointed out, this might need fleshing out. It was intended as a simplified example rather than a thorough solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare the images, just maintain the index of the current image in a variable.

Here's an example that works for any number of images:

```
private int _currentImageIndex;
private string[] _imagePaths =
{
    "Images/Enemy.png",
    "Images/Enemy2.png",
    "Images/Enemy3.png",
};


...


void NextImage()
{
    // Dispose the current image
    Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
    if (img != null)
        img.Dispose();

    // Show the next image
    _currentImageIndex = (_currentImageIndex + 1) % _imagePaths.Length;
    string path = _imagePaths[_currentImageIndex];
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to compare ImageLocation. Although it doesn't work if you have your pictures as resources.

```
if (PictureBox1.ImageLocation == PictureBox2.ImageLocation)
{

}
```

See my question:
[Dynamically changing image in a picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20644589/dynamically-changing-image-in-a-picturebox)

Answer (score 0):

Here goes simple answer.

In case of just 2 images, use flag

```
// field, true if enemy2.png is loaded
bool _image2;

// somewhere
if(_image2)
{
    myImage = Image.FromFile(@"Images/Enemy.png");
    _image2 = false;
}
else
{
    myImage = Image.FromFile(@"Images/Enemy2.png");
    _image2 = true;
}
```